# geopandas error "OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll" in PyCharm using OSGeo4W paths

Tags: python, qgis-3, geopandas, osgeo4w, pycharm

Using https://spatialgalaxy.net/2018/02/13/quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis3-on-windows/ I created a .bat file to load the OSGeo4W and QGIS paths into PyCharm. Now I am getting an error importing geopandas with

```
import geopandas "OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll"
```

I can find the dll in my OSGeo4W folder and I can import geopandas in QGIS.

Bat File

```
    @echo off
    SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
    call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
    call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat
    @echo off
    path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
    path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\lib
    path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W3\apps\Qt5\bin
    path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W3\apps\Python39\Scripts

    set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
    set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39

    set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin\pycharm64.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

To get geopandas working in a OSGeo Pycharm environment you need to import qgis processing using...

```
from qgis import processing
```

then...

```
import geopandas
```

will bring in the geopandas package

EDIT 20220513

```
import qgis
```

Will also work.

Comment: That's odd! Did you try to import other modules like PyQt? That's where my IDE fails: from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

Comment: I assume that PyCharm is using the Interpreter from apps/Python39 and not from bin?
By the way, I have an open ticket in the osgeo4w trac system on this bug: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/735

Comment: As for my Python dir it is using the OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe
I can switch to OSGeo4W\bin\python.exe and I don't get errors on importing the PyQt5.QtCore stuff geopandas also imports. I'm not an expert, this just worked for me it might cause me issue later on.

Comment: I stumbled onto from qgis import processing as a solution by playing with some code I copied out of the QGIS model builder. FYI import qgis also works, it appears geopandas and perhaps the PyQt5 is installed within the processing module. Pycharm still shows a red exclamation mark saying it cannot find reference QtCore or QVariant but the script runs with no errors so I am assuming it is importing those components as well. Full disclosure, I'm not an expert I completely stumbled onto this and I yet to have found current directions for getting Pycharm setup with QGIS\OSGeo parameters.

Comment: I'm using PyScripter and discovered the same error than you. If the code runs in the QGIS-Console, everything is fine, even when using the command line interpreter in the OsGeo4w-Shell. But any "external" IDE fails. I'm just guessing, that the IDE uses the python3.exe from apps/Python39 and that this causes the import error.

Comment: Yes, I experience the same issue; in Pycharm to get around it I used the import qgis and the import qgis doesn't seem to have an effect in the python console in QGIS so I can copy and past the code back and fourth without changing it. So far that is, as I get into my project further and call more tools this might change.